# Shadowbox opens in _blank when width and/or height are set

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I've been searching everywhere on the internet now but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I'm using the shadowbox for my galleries and it's working perfectly fine if I don't use a fixed height or/and width. If I set one or both of these attributes the link opens in a _blank page.

This is what my code looks like

```
<div id="imprint">
   <a href="subpages/imprint.html" rel="shadowbox;width=645" title="Imprint">
        Imprint
   </a>
</div>
```

thanks for your replies 
mlp

update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var options = {
        resizeLgImages:     true,
        displayNav:         false,
        handleUnsupported:  'remove',
        keysClose:          ['c', 27] // c or esc
    };

    Shadowbox.init(options);

});

</script>
```

Comment: here is an update.... I just tried deleting the width but leaving the semi-colon... it doesn't matter what I write into the rel="" it only works with the lean rel="shadowbox"

Comment: I just checked the documentation, and you wrote it exactly as it should be defined. My guess is that your problem lies elsewhere. Could you post more code? Like the Shadowbox.init or other HTML/JS content?

Comment: hi Adrien, I just added my init to the upper post. I think I might have the problems solution, because I just tried the custombox and found out, that it only works on a server or a virtual server.... is this the same for the shadowbox?